# Get String as Date in HSQL

Tags: sql, hsqldb

```
select * 
from employee 
having to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = to_date('01/01/2012 10:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Column 'date' is a VARCHAR/STRING

as to_date doesnt work in HSQL,  how can make the above query work in HSQL ??

Comment: from employee bean where to_date(bean.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = to_date('01/01/2012 10:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: TO_DATE func doesnt work in HSQL. And I want do it in nativeQuery ..

Comment: use Criteria as emp.createCriteria(employee.class)
 .add(Restrictions.eq("date", new java.sql.Date("YourValue")))
 .list()

Comment: The having clause does not make any sense, you should be using `where` for this condition.

Comment: Is it possible in native query, because the date column is a string in the table

Comment: with WHERE clause , can i have a function on the left hand side ?? FUNCTION(column) = ?

Comment: Yes of course. Why wouldn't it? The `having` clause is intended to work on groups defined by a `group by  clause. According to the manual, HSQL **does** support the to_date() function:http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N13EE8

Comment: @sethukrs to_date will work in hibernate3. If you want to use native query use as " select * from table where to_date(column and formate) = to_date(your value and formate)"  session.createSQLQuery("Your Query");

Answer (score 2):

TO_DATE does work with latest versions HSQLDB. You can use version 2.2.9 or future release versions.

But your query is wrong as indicated in comment by a_horse_with_no_name and needs WHERE instead of HAVING.

```
select * 
from employee 
where to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = to_date('01/01/2012 10:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

In fact you can also simplify the query

```
select * 
from employee 
where to_date(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = timestamp'2012-01-01 10:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but it is the top google result so it is probably better to update it than start a new one - especially I have solved my problem. I had a massive problem with this query (hsqldb version 2.3.2) where my date is a string created in java and stored as a varchar in the database.

**The to_date call doesn't work without a cast for me** and the documentation was a bit vague on how to make the cast correctly (I thought the varchar cast needs to be done specifying the actual length while it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
select * from table2 where to_date(cast(timestamp as VARCHAR(254)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') > to_date('2015-09-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

**notice the cast(xxx as VARCHAR(254)) there!**